# Hints for java.lang.String.replace problem?

Tags: java, string, replace

I would like to replace "." by "," in a String/double that I want to write to a file.

Using the following Java code

```
double myDouble = myObject.getDoubleMethod(); // returns 38.1882352941176
System.out.println(myDouble);

String myDoubleString = "" + myDouble;
System.out.println(myDoubleString);

myDoubleString.replace(".", ",");
System.out.println(myDoubleString);

myDoubleString.replace('.', ',');
System.out.println(myDoubleString);
```

I get the following output

```
38.1882352941176
38.1882352941176
38.1882352941176
38.1882352941176
```

Why isn't replace doing what it is supposed to do? I expect the last two lines to contain a ",".

Do I have to do/use something else? Suggestions?

Comment: This has tripped up soooo many Java newbies over the years.

Comment: I have re-read the docs of replace and it clearly starts with
"Returns a new string ..." ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to assign the new value back to the variable.

```
double myDouble = myObject.getDoubleMethod(); // returns 38.1882352941176
System.out.println(myDouble);

String myDoubleString = "" + myDouble;
System.out.println(myDoubleString);

myDoubleString = myDoubleString.replace(".", ",");
System.out.println(myDoubleString);

myDoubleString = myDoubleString.replace('.', ',');
System.out.println(myDoubleString);
```

Comment: As usual the problem sits in front of the computer ;-) Thx

Comment: The reason it returns a new string is that Strings are immutable in Java.

Answer (score 11):

The original String isn't being modified. The call returns the modified string, so you'd need to do this:

```
String modded = myDoubleString.replace(".",",");
System.out.println( modded );
```

Answer (score 10):

The bigger question is why not use [`DecimalFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instead of doing String replace?

Comment: Very good point! Your answer goes beyond my question, but solves the problem that I essentially had. I didn't know DecimalFormat, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`replace` **returns a new String** (since String is immutable in Java):

```
String newString = myDoubleString.replace(".", ",");
```

Comment: But you need not introduce `newString`, because although `String` objects are immutable,  references to `String` objects can be changed (if they are not `final`): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Always remember, Strings are immutable.  They can't change.  If you're calling a String method that changes it in some way, you need to store the return value.  Always.

I remember getting caught out with this more than a few times at Uni :)