# Syntax error on token "super", invalid Name

Tags: java

I am trying to write the Undergrad class which extends Students

here is the base class (Student)

```
public class Student{

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private double gpa;

    public Student(){

    }

    public Student(int id, String name, double gpa){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }

    public Student(int id, double gpa){
        this(id, "", gpa);
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public double getGPA(){
        return gpa;
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Student:\nID: " + id + "\nName: " + name + "\nGPA: " + gpa;
    }
}
```

and here the derived class (Undergrad)

```
public class Undergrad extends Student {

    private String year;

    public Undergrad (int id , String name ,double gpa,String year)
    {
        super(id,name , gpa);
        this.year =year;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super() + " the year is :" + year;
    }
}
```

the problem i'm facing is that eclipse shows that I have
 a mistake in    **toString** method  in class    **Undergrad**
exactly at the **super()** invoke the error says

> "Syntax error on token "super", invalid Name"

could I find any help please ?

Comment: You are looking for `super.toString()` assuming you want to call the super class implementation of the method.

Comment: When you write `super()`, it is actually like telling the compiler "please invoke the superclass constructor for me". If you just want a "pointer" to the superclass, you should use the idiom above, as suggested by @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Comment: @Mauren In Java , Do we have pointers ?

Comment: @iShaalan not in the C sense, but yes, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750106/how-can-i-use-pointers-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super()` call is allowed only in constructors.
you need to call `super.toString()` if you want to call super class method.

```
public String toString()
{
      return super.toString() + " the year is :" + year;
 }
```

This is the syntax for `super` keyword
 1.for calling a superclass constructor is

> 1. super();  //the superclass no-argument constructor is called
> 2. super(parameter list);//the superclass constructor with a matching parameter list is called

2.for calling a superclass member is

> 1. super.fieldName;//here member is field of super class
> 2. super.methodName();//here member is method of super class

Answer (score 2):

When calling a superclass method, use the syntax `super.methodName()`:

```
{return super.toString() + " the year is :" + year;}
```

This is different from calling a superclass constructor from within a subclass constructor; that syntax just needs the keyword `super` with no dot and no method name, as you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

`super.toString()` to call the super class method.

`super()` calls the super class constructor.