# How does pointing to objects work in java?

Tags: java, variables, pointers, reference

So, lets say I have 2 arrays defined like this:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = a;

a[1] = 35; // b[1] becomes 35
b[0] = -5; // why would a[0] become -5?
```

So, I can reason that changing a value in *a* will automatically change the value in *b* (*b* is pointing to *a*). But, if I change value in *b*, why would it affect *a*? Wouldn't that be as if *a* is pointing to *b* (they are interchangeable)?

I was confused with this concept and would like some clarification. 
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In your code `a` and `b` are references to the **same** memory location.

Comment: This might help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1750197/3226981

Comment: `a` and `b` are both pointing to the same object which is something _else_ off in memory somewhere.  `b` isn't pointing to `a`, it's pointing to the same object that `a` is pointing to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do an analogy here. The objects (such as arrays) that you create are like balloons. And the variables (a and b) are like children. And the children can hold a single balloon with a string. And that string is what we call a *reference*. On the other hand, one balloon can be held by multiple children.

In your code, you created a single balloon i.e. an array `{1, 2, 3}`. And let a child called `a` hold it. Now you can tell child `a` to modify items in the array because the child `a` is holding it.

In the second line, you tell another child `b` to hold the balloon that `a` is holding, like this:

```
int[] b = a;
```

Now `a` and `b` are actually holding the same balloon!

When you do this:

```
a[1] = 35;
```

Not only is the balloon that `a` is holding been changed, but also is the balloon held by `b` been changed. Because, well, `a` and `b` are holding the *same* balloon.

The same thing happens when you do:

```
b[0] = -5;
```

That's how reference types work in Java. But please note that this doesn't apply to primitive types, such as `int` or `float`.

For example,

```
int a = 10;
int b = a;
b = 20; //a is not equal to 20!!!
```

Comment: Thank you all, for all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the variable `int[] a = {1,2,3};`, by using the brackets { } just as by saying `new int[n]` java allocates enough memory for those values and now `a` references that address in memory.

Then, when you create the new variable `int[] b = a;`, you aren't allocating memory to that variable `b`, rather `b` references the same address which `a` references.

Now, when you change something in `a` or `b` the change occurs at the address referenced by both those variables and will be reflected by both.

Answer (score 1):

Because Java Array is considered Reference Object.

```
int[] b = a;    // variable 'b' points same memory location with 'a'
```

If you want to copy all value of a, write code below

```
@Test
public void arrayCopy1() {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] b = a;

    System.out.println(a); //Point [I@64a294a6
    System.out.println(b); //Point [I@64a294a6

    printArrayValues(a);   //[1,2,3]
    printArrayValues(b);   //[1,2,3]
    a[0] = 10;
    printArrayValues(a);   //[10,2,3]
    printArrayValues(b);   //[10,2,3]
}

@Test
public void arrayCopy2() {
    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);

    System.out.println(a); //Point [I@64a294a6
    System.out.println(b); //Point [I@7e0b37bc

    printArrayValues(a);   //[1,2,3]
    printArrayValues(b);   //[1,2,3]
    a[0] = 10;
    printArrayValues(a);   //[10,2,3]
    printArrayValues(b);   //[1,2,3]
}

private void printArrayValues(int[] arr) {
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
        if (i != arr.length-1)
            System.out.print(",");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you set `int[] b = a` you didn't simply copied the values of `a` and gave them to `b` you gave to `b` the memory location of `a`, therefore if you change one, you change the other