# a double- ended priority queue implemention with two priority queues,if i delete max in maxPQ, how to delete the same data in the minPQ in O(logn)

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, reference

Here is my code:

```
 public DoubleEndedPriorityQueue(){
     max = new MaxPQ<Element>();
     min = new MinPQ<Element>();
 }
 public void insert(Key item){
     Element thisElement = new Element(item);
     Element thatElement = new Element(item);
     thisElement.element = thatElement;
     thatElement.element = thisElement;
     max.insert(thisElement);
     min.insert(thatElement);
 }
 private class Element{
     Key item;
     Element element;
     private Element(){}
     private Element(Key item){
         this(item,null);
     }
     private Element(Key item,Element element){
         this.item = item;
         this.element = element;
     }
 }
```

}

i create a data-structure to store a key and the reference pointing to the element which  stored the same key in another array(the priority queue is implemented by the array),the problem is:if i find a element in an array ,i want to find the element with the same key in another array in o(1) which means  i can know its index in O(1), how can i do it?

Comment: What makes you think you can?

Comment: In C,i can use a pointer to get it,so i want to do the same thing in java

Comment: _i want to do the same thing in java_ Why would you want to reproduce a feature that was hidden in Java, Java doesn't provide pointers. You have the reference, you can do what you want on the instance with that.

Comment: The nearest equivalent of storing the pointer would be to store the index in the other array.

Comment: Why would you want to reproduce a feature that was hide in Java, Java doesn't provide pointers.   because i think it can be easy to find its position

Comment: Unless you directly store the element index in the instance, you can't do this in constant time in Java.

Comment: Using the index would still be o(n) but that would be the closest thing (but that's gonna be funny to maintain ;) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use pointers in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750106/how-can-i-use-pointers-in-java). **Depending on your needs**, you could create a Wrapper class to be your `Cell`, those wrapper reference would be the pointer you need.

Comment: Unless you directly store the element index in the instance, you can't do this in constant time in Java.That sounds bad.It's the first step of my solution to implement a method delmax() in a double-ended  priority queue, if i can't find it in O(1), how can i implement it in O(logn)

Comment: Store the array elements in order, according to some `Comparator`, then use [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of How can I use pointers in Java?. Depending on your needs, you could create a Wrapper class to be your Cell, those wrapper reference would be the pointer you need.Sorry it can't solve this specific problem for me.

Comment: Store the array elements in order, according to some Comparator, then use Arrays.binarySearch. But in the priority implemented by the array,every data may  swim and sink,its index isn't instant.i'm afraid that your solution can't do that.

Comment: Save yourself all the trouble and ditch the idea of trying to keep two priority queues in synch. Implement a [Min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) and be done with it.