# Java - Changing variable value without accessing it

Tags: java

I want to change the variable value without changing it directly, In C or C++ we may use pointers or reference variable to do that since no pointer concept in java, how we can do that.
in C we may do like this

```
int var=10;
int *ptr;
ptr=&var;
*ptr++;
printf("%d",var);
```

**output :11**
Is there is any other way to do same thing in java ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't ;) And why would you do that in `Java` ?

Comment: In Java everything is a reference (slap me if I'm slightly off).

Comment: Java has pointers, but you cannot manipulate them like in C++ or C

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you please give me simple code snippet using reference.please

Comment: @KennethClark how can we implement.any example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750106/how-can-i-use-pointers-in-java

Comment: You *are* accessing the variable. You're dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the variable value without changing it directly"?  You either set the variable to a value, or you don't.

Answer (score 3):

All the primitive types in Java (byte, short, int, long, float, double, boolean, char) are call by value, so with these, no, you can't do it. You can do it with objects though, as those are references.

Example:

```
public class MyInt {
    public int value;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyInt i1 = new MyInt();
    i1.value = 2;
    MyInt i2 = i1;
    i2.value++;
    System.out.println(i1.value);
}
```

Comment: your example is missing

Comment: sorry messed up, added it now ^^

Comment: Example please.

Comment: what does it print?

Comment: it prints 3, as bothi1 and i2 are references to the same object