# Java Regex not working?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to send the following parameters to a server through HTTP POST:

```
["my_session_id","{this=that, foo=bar}"]
```

But the server is returning a parse error because of the quotes around the hash.

I am trying to remove them with a regex like so:

```
params.replaceAll("\\\"\\{", "\\{");
params.replaceAll("\\\"\\}", "\\}");
```

In all honestly I have no idea what I'm doing. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: send value as JSONobject because you will get values from jsonobect on service side easy without using replace or split functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues here: First, you're not re-assigning the string. [`String`s are immutable in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553110/1438733) (cannot be changed), so you must assign the result. Second, you're replacing `"}` instead of `}"`.

Here's what I used:

```
String params = "[\"my_session_id\",\"{this=that, foo=bar}\"]";
params = params.replaceAll("\\\"\\{", "\\{");
params = params.replaceAll("\\}\\\"", "\\}");
System.out.println(params);
```

Which prints out:

> `["my_session_id",{this=that, foo=bar}]`

PS: Bit of advice, use [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Android has [excellent JSON handling](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html), and it is [supported in PHP as well](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Are the `/`'s in `params` created by `toString()` ?

Comment: @TheVasari Those are there to escape the `"`s when I created the string. In my code, `params` is initially equal to `["my_session_id","{this=that, foo=bar}"]`, just like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using the regular expression replaceAll?  Alternatively, you might try:

```
 String parameters = parameters.replace("{", "\\{").replace("}", "\\}");
```