# Java Strings are immutable?

Tags: java, oop

Why are Java strings considered immutable? I can say `String name = "Paul";` and later on change name value to `name = "Henry";`. Where is immutability coming from?

Comment: You are not changing the previous string object, instead you are making and assigning new object to `name`.

Comment: Five Good Reasons: [Why String is immutable or final in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2010/10/why-string-is-immutable-in-java.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object itself didn't change.

What you have done is the following

```
name <- String("Paul")
name <- String("Henry")
```

String("Paul") has been not been changed.

Try the following:

```
String a = "test";
String b = a;
a = "test2";

System.out.println(b);
```

Answer (score 3):

A new string is created, they are definitely immutable and interned btw.

You can't do this :

```
String name = "Paul"; // in effect the same as new String("Paul");
name.setValue("Henry")
```

becuase a string is immutable you have to create a completely new object.

Comment: How and yet name is the object and its value has been changed to "Henry" ?

Comment: @PaulOdero: `name` is not the object. `name` is a reference to a (String) object. At first it's a reference to the `"Paul"` object, later you change that reference to point to the `"Henry"` object. The `"Paul"` object does not change, because it is immutable.

Comment: @jlordo Does both `"Paul"` `"Henry"` exists in String pool. so that intially `name` pointed to `"Paul"` and then to `"Henry"`

Comment: @SanKrish no, see update

Answer (score 1):

Distinguish between the variable: name, which is referring to a String and the String it refers to.

name originally pointed to the String "Paul", later you changed it to point somewhere else, "Paul" itself was unaffected.

Consider

```
 String name = "Paul";
 String name1 = name;

 name = "Peter";
```

what does name1 refer to now?