# Java PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition on string substitution?

Tags: java, regex, string, exception

I am trying to write a method that will accept a `String`, inspect it for instances of certain tokens (e.g. `${fizz}`, `${buzz}`, `${foo}`, etc.) and replace each token with a new string that is fetched from a `Map<String,String>`.

For example, if I pass this method the following string:

> "How now ${fizz} cow. The ${buzz} had oddly-shaped ${foo}."

And if the method consulted the following `Map<String,String>`:

```
Key             Value
==========================
"fizz"          "brown"
"buzz"          "arsonist"
"foo"           "feet"
```

Then the resultant string would be:

> "How now brown cow. The arsonist had oddly-shaped feet."

Here is my method:

```
String substituteAllTokens(Map<String,String> tokensMap, String toInspect) {
    String regex = "\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toInspect);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String token = matcher.group();     // Ex: ${fizz}
        String tokenKey = matcher.group(1); // Ex: fizz
        String replacementValue = null;

        if(tokensMap.containsKey(tokenKey))
            replacementValue = tokensMap.get(tokenKey);
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("String contained an unsupported token.");

        toInspect = toInspect.replaceFirst(token, replacementValue);
    }

    return toInspect;
}
```

When I run this, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
${fizz}
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1730)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.closure(Pattern.java:2792)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:1906)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1769)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1477)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1150)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:840)
    at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2158)
    ...rest of stack trace omitted for brevity (but available upon request!)
```

**Why am I getting this? And what is the correct fix?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In `${fizz}`

`{` is an indicator to the regex engine that you are about to start a repetition indicator, like `{2,4}` which means '2 to 4 times of the previous token'. But `{f` is illegal, because it has to be followed by a number, so it throws an exception.

You need to escape all regex metacharacters (in this case `$`, `{` and `}`) (try using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String) ) or use a different method that substitutes a string for a string, not a regex for a string.

Comment: The `{` is escaped though: `"\\$\\{([^}]*)\\}"`

Comment: @Brian No it's not. Stack trace: `at java.lang.String.replaceFirst(String.java:2158)` refers to this line: `toInspect = toInspect.replaceFirst(token, replacementValue);` And `token`'s value is `${fizz}`, with no escaping.

Comment: Ah, yes! Of course. Read too fast, I guess. +1 Maybe you could elaborate more on what exactly is being passed in and why it's failing.

Comment: Exactly - I'm still struggling to put your answer into motion, but thanks @Patashu and +1!

Comment: @TicketMonster `replaceFirst` expects a regular expression in the first argument, just like the `Pattern.compile` method. However, you're passing it `${fizz}` without any escaping. Use [`Pattern.quote(token)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) before passing `token` in.

Comment: that still doesn't answer the question..after replacing string matcher would point to invalid position!

Comment: @TicketMonster your code would not replace properly even after escaping it..matcher would point to an invalid position..for example try replacing this `${fizz}${buzz}` where fizz is mapped to an **empty string**

Comment: @Anirudh Again, strings are immutable. Changing the `toInspect` *reference* does nothing to the string that the `Matcher` is using (the original `toInspect` reference).

Comment: ahh..ok..in this case it would work since op is performing linear search for `${}` but still..changing string to which matcher refers to is dangerous

Comment: @Anirudh Looks like this solution works to me: http://ideone.com/AocIh6 Your solution enters an infinite loop by the way.

Comment: @Anirudh You can't change the string to which matcher refers to because strings are immutable.

Comment: @Anirudh [Read this please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java).

Comment: @Brian it should be `matcher.reset(toInspect);` and i **never** said its `mutable` i said matcher would point to invalid position.op's code `works` becuase he's replacing through string **not** matcher,..(missed it).see [this](http://ideone.com/nnrdnz) and remove reset line.it won't run

Comment: @Patashu replace it through `matcher` not `toInspect` i.e `matcher.replaceFirst`

Comment: @Anirudh "Invoking this method changes this matcher's state. If the matcher is to be used in further matching operations then it should first be reset." This rule only applies if you use replaceFirst on the matcher itself. The OP did NOT, so why even bring it up?

Comment: @Patashu i had misinterpreted the question to which i came know minutes ago..:P

Comment: Strings are mutable if you allow reflection. http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/12oop/MutableString.java.html
But this has nothing to do with the original question anyway.

Comment: i know this is very old thread, but now I am facing same issue, can some one please advise me on concreate solution for this, Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out by Patashu, the problem is in `replaceFirst(token, replacementValue)`, that expects a regex in the first argument, not a literal. Change it to `replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(token), replacementValue)` and you will do alright.

I also changed a bit the first regex, as it goes faster with `+` instead of `*` but that's not necessary.

```
static String substituteAllTokens(Map<String,String> tokensMap, String toInspect) {
    String regex = "\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toInspect);
    String result = toInspect;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String token = matcher.group();     // Ex: ${fizz}
        String tokenKey = matcher.group(1); // Ex: fizz
        String replacementValue = null;

        if(tokensMap.containsKey(tokenKey))
            replacementValue = tokensMap.get(tokenKey);
        else
            throw new RuntimeException("String contained an unsupported token.");

        result = result.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(token), replacementValue);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If you want to get *really* picky about speed, use `[^}]++` to make it possessive instead of just greedy so it will never backtrack.

Comment: The speed results are surprising: using my method, the original regex (`[^}]*`) took 37.04 ms to run 10000 times, my regex (`[^}]+`) took 37.35 ms and suggested regex (`[^}]++`) 36.98 ms. Almost no difference.

Comment: For a longer input `"How now ${fizz} cow. The ${buzz} had oddly-shaped ${foo}.How now ${fizz} cow. The ${buzz} had oddly-shaped ${foo}.${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}"` the results were different for regex. The original regex (`[^}]*`) took 515.47 ms to run 10000 times, my regex (`[^}]+`) took 514.41 ms and regex suggested by @Brian (`[^}]++`) 507.41 ms. Still close, but Brian's did better.

Comment: Did you use an actual benchmarking tool to check like [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)? Also, you should make sure that you test with partially matched strings as well, such as `The ${fizz cow` with no terminating `}`. Also, to be fair, I said *really* picky :3

Comment: No, I wrote the benchmarking myself. Did a warm-up loop in the beginning to activate hotspot and called `System.gc()` several times outside measurement. But, yes, I know it is not bulletproof. I didn't know about Caliper, though. Good to know it!

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from `Matcher.replaceAll`

```
boolean result = matcher.find();
if (result) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    do {
        String tokenKey = matcher.group(1); // Ex: fizz
        String replacement = Matcher.quoteReplacement(tokensMap.get(tokenKey));
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
        result = matcher.find();
    } while (result);
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Adding here my test results using this method:
the original regex (`[^}]*`) took 15.14 ms to run 10000 times, my regex (`[^}]+`) took 14.88 ms and regex suggested by @Brian (`[^}]++`) 15.89 ms. As I said before this method is a absolute winner in terms of speed and here my regex fits better :)

Comment: @Miguel Try to use a very long `toInspect` as input, such as `"${fizz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${foo}...${fizz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${foo}"` (I bet my `StringBuffer` will be faster than your `String`, when the length grow, it won't be only 3x faster.)

Comment: Using `"How now ${fizz} cow. The ${buzz} had oddly-shaped ${foo}.How now ${fizz} cow. The ${buzz} had oddly-shaped ${foo}.${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}${fizz}${foo}${buzz}${buzz}${foo}${fizz}${foo}${fizz}${buzz}"` as the input this method performed even better then mine, it was 5x faster. The results were different for regex. The original regex (`[^}]*`) took 92.94 ms to run 10000 times, my regex (`[^}]+`) took 93.6 ms and regex suggested by @Brian (`[^}]++`) 91.83 ms. Brian's did better. Why is that so?

Comment: @Miguel I only know about 3x->5x: 1. `replaceFirst` use a regex again, which is unnecessary. 2. In a loop, `StringBuffer` concats `String` faster than directly in `String`, since `String` generate a new `String` everytime. Which regex to use is not important.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your RegEx a bit ugly, but 
this will work

```
String regex = "\\$[\\{]([^}]*)[\\}]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String-replaceAll.
Sample input String for testing
"SESSIONKEY1":

> "${SOMESTRING.properties.SESSIONKEY1}"

,

```
    String pattern = "\\\"\\$\\{SOMESTRING\\.[^\\}]+\\}\\\""; 
    System.out.println(pattern);
    String result = inputString.replaceAll(pattern, "null");
    return result.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the input String and it contains $ or { then use this way

```
public static String replacemyownSubStr(String i, String target, String replacement) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int index = i.indexOf(target);
        while (index >= 0) {
            result.append(i.substring(lastIndex, index));
            result.append(replacement);
            lastIndex = index + target.length();
            index = i.indexOf(target, lastIndex);
        }
        result.append(i.substring(lastIndex));
        return result.toString();
    }
```