# Wanted regular expression for the string ${username}

Tags: java, regex

The catch is username can also have `$` symbol in it for example `$mahanta`. My regex is

```
\${([^}]+)}
```

But this does not work.As the language is java and the regex expression is String I escaped the `$` with another backslash.Even added 2 more backslashes.But gives run-time exception.

Comment: Escape the first `{` char. To feel more confident, you may also escape the last `}` char, too.

Comment: This will need a little more context. For instance, in a Java String expressing a regex, you typically have double escapes. Also you might need to add you expected input/output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^}]+)}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("${$mat}");
        System.out.println("matcher = " + matcher);
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println("matches = " + matches);
        String group = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println("group = " + group);
    }
}
```

See [Java PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition on string substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462146/java-patternsyntaxexception-illegal-repetition-on-string-substitution) on why that `{` needs to be escaped.