# How to Remove special characters at the end and at the begging of the string

Tags: java, string

I have a string:

```
String str = "    line0\n" +
                "line1\n" +
                "line2    line0\n" +
                "line3\n" +
                "line4   \n"
```

How can I get the following script:

```
String formatedStr = "line0\n" +
                    "line1\n" +
                    "line2    line0\n" +
                    "line3\n" +
                    "line4"
```

Comment: `formatedStr.trim()`

Comment: `String formatedStr = str.trim();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to trim a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291307/correct-way-to-trim-a-string-in-java)

Comment: s = s.replaceAll("^\\s+||\\s+\n$", "");

Comment: `formatedStr.trim().replace("(^\\\\n*|(\\\\n)$)", "")`   use regex to replace leading and trailing character with empty string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it as follows

`String formattedStr = str.trim();`

Refer [java-string-trim-method-example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-string-trim-method-example/) for more details.