# Are Strings overwritable?

Tags: java, string, immutability, overwrite

My textbook says a `String` is **not over-writable or immutable**, i.e, once you enter the value of a String you can't change it. But today when I was running the following code, the `String str` *gets muted* as the compiler does not give any error and the new `String a`'s value is successfully entered into `str`.

```
class Test
{
static void main()
{
    String str = "something";
    String a ="anything";
    str = a; //str is being over written without any error
    System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

The output is : anything

*So, is my book wrong ?*

If my book is not wrong please give an example to show that `String`s are immutable

Comment: You are changing reference variable not the string. refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct. When you say `str = a` you are not changing anything about the `String` 'something'. You should distinguish between `str` and `something`, they are not the same. `"something"` here is a String object in memory, whereas `str` is just the reference to that string. Same with the reference `a`.

When you say:

```
str = a
```

You are not changing `something`, you are in fact saying, "change the reference `str` to point to whatever the reference `a` is pointing to." The `String`s remain the same, the references change.

On a similar note, this is why you may see in your book that concatenating `String`s is expensive, as doing something like:

`str = str + a`

Would again not be changing the existing `String`s, but instead creating a new `String` object which is equal to the concatenation of the `String` that the reference `str` is referring to and the `String` that the reference `a` is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what immutable means. In your scenario you are just changing references.

```
str = a;
```

will make both `a` and `str` to point to String `"anything"`. The Text Book is correct. `String` is immutable and can not be overwritten. If you check the JavaDoc for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Most of the methods return a `String`. This is because any operation in a `String` will not change that `String` object but will result in a new `String` being created. Effectively you can never change a `String` after you create it. By Change I mean append new characters, remove characters without a new `String` object being created.

Comment: your answer is not satisfactory

Answer (score 1):

As many answers already point out is that you only change references. Immutable means you cannot change the string itself. for example you do:

```
String a = "anything";
System.out.println(a); // -> anything

a.substring(3);
System.out.println(a); // -> anything : this is because the String itself is 
                      //               immutable.

a = a.substring(3);
System.out.println(a); // -> thing : this is what immutable means to edit a string 
                      //            you must reassign it or assign it 
                      //            to a new variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the reference of `str` to `a`. So `str` effectively becomes `a`'s value.

Comment: Deleted the original comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

they are just pointer to that string. so when you do `str =a` , you just assign pointer of `a` to `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the String object is not being changed.  What's happening is that a new String object is being assigned to the variable.  The old String object still exists in memory but you just can't refer to it any more.  The 'str' variable now refers to the String object containing "anything" but the String containing "something" still exists as it did before.  Try assigning 'str' to another variable first and then, after assigning 'a' to 'str', check that other variable and you'll see that it still says "something", proving that that String was not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the value of a variable is never an *object*, but a *reference*. Relevant to your case, the type `String` on the `a` variable says the variable is allowed to contain only references to `String` objects.

You can update the value in the variable, sure; but that won't touch the object it is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

**Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created.**

The String object is created and stored on constant pool or literal pool.

In your case, when you say,

```
String str="something"; // An object is created on constant pool with value 'something' and reference 'str' is pointing to it.

String a="anything"; // An object is created on constant pool with value 'anything' and reference 'a' is pointing to it.
```

And when you do, str=a; then 'str' actually start pointed to 'a', but the object with value as 'something' remains on constant pool with the same value.

Comment: then what does 'something' refer to?

Comment: 'something' can't refer to any object. It is itself an object so it can be "referred by" some other reference but it cant "refer to" others.
In this case, "something" is not referred by any reference.