# How can you say String is immutable since you can change it?

Tags: java, string

Since String is Immutable How can we will change String for Example

```
String s1="Hello";
  String s2="Manas";
```

Now I am making

```
s1=s1+s3;
```

It will Print "Hello Manas". So String s1 will change.

So how can u say that String is immutable?

Comment: Immutable != `final`. Look up the terms for more info

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1552301/1883647). Did you mean `s1=s1+s2;`?

Comment: A String is immutable.  `s1` and `s2` are not String objects, they are *references* to String objects and these references can be changed.

Comment: Immutable means By default final So how can u change the final variable or references.

Answer (score 6):

You're not changing the contents of `"Hello"`, you're changing the value of the variable `s1` to refer to a different string object entirely.

Immutability has nothing to do with changing the value of the variable - if you want to prevent that, you can make the variable in question final.

Comment: You're not changing the value of the reference - you're changing the value of the *variable* to be a different reference. (Just like `int x = 0; x = 5;` doesn't change what 0 means, it changes the value of `x` to 5.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah sorry, bad wording on my part. Fixed now.

Comment: It not like (int x = 0; x = 5) it's like (final int x = 0; x=5;) So how can u change final variable.