# Closures in Java & immutable Strings. How does this program work?

Tags: java, closures

Here is the program

```
public class Closure {

     public String foo = "";

     public static Closure process(final Closure t) {
          System.out.println(t.toString() + " = " + t.foo);
          t.foo = "bar";
          new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                System.out.println(t.toString() + " = " + t.foo);
                t.foo = "baz";
             }
          }.run();
          System.out.println(t.toString() + " = " + t.foo);
          return t;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       process(new Closure());
    }

}
```

When I execute it, all 3 prints show the same reference for the variable t.foo. This makes sense for Closures, it is as we expect it.

What puzzles me is that in Java Strings are immutable. So if we reassign the string, shouldn't the reference change?

Comment: Did you try to reassign it to see what happens? Where is you engineering spirit?

Comment: What do you mean by "shouldn't the references change"? Shouldn't *which* references change? I suspect you're confused about what the immutability of String really means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foo property is a reference. This is a misunderstanding of what it means for a string to be immutable in Java.

See [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It is a little confusing to be using `Closure` when the question doesn't contain any closures.

The output of your program should look like (Ideone wants a class with this name instead of Closure)

```
Ideone@1e61582 = 
Ideone@1e61582 = bar
Ideone@1e61582 = baz
```

see http://ideone.com/c5HzEF

As you can see the reference `foo` is changing.  The reference `t` which is what you print, doesn't change as expected.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you print the reference of the `Closure` object, not of the `String`.