# About String object and pass-by-value in Java

Tags: java

I khow that java is pass-by-value, and when i pass a object into method and change it,it will change when i out method. But i can't do it with `String` object. This is example:

```
public class text 
{
    public void change(String a)
    {
        a = "ha";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        text a = new text();
        String b = "hi";
        a.change(b);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java <-- The answer you want and a lot more.

Comment: Research on these "Java String literals", "String intern". I am sure after these you won't be having same questions.

Comment: Assignment is an operation on variables, not objects. Assigning a new value to a variable doesn't change other variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "ha";
```

That statement is analogous to this:

```
a = new String("ha");
```

So even if `String` were not immutable, you'd have the issue that you are now pointing `a` to a new String object.

What is happening here is just "compiler magic" or "syntactic sugar" to make it easier to declare a String.

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case, String is an immutable object. All you are saying in your change method is for "a" to point to a new object, but that "a" is a different pointer than your main "a" pointer.