# How can I replace JSON element in JSON object with another string in java?

Tags: java, json

JSON object :

```
{
  "test1":"2",
  "test2":"4",
  "test3":"5"
}
```

I need to replace `"test2":"4"` with `"test2":"this is test"`.

How can I do this with Java?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to replace `"test2":"4"` by `"this is test"` string.
>
> How can I do this with java?.

Using [`String API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), for example with [`String::replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)), remembering:

- [Strings in Java are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)
- You need to [scape special characters](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96)

  ```
    String result = yourJsonString.replace("\"test2\":\"4\"", "\"test2\":\"this is test\"");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace string "test2":"4" with "this is test" then it will make your json unparsable and if you want to change the content to the key "test2" from "4" to "this is test" then you can use JSON parser apis like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) etc.