# String.replace isn't working

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CashSplitter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Cash Values");
        String i = S.nextLine();
        for(int b = 0;b<i.length(); b ++){
            System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(i.substring(0,i.indexOf('.')+3));

        i.replace(i.substring(0, i.indexOf('.') + 3), "");
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(i.substring(0, i.indexOf('.') + 3));
        }
    }
}
```

The code should be able to take a string with multiple cash values and split them up, into individual values. For example 7.32869.32 should split out 7.32, 869.32 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is immutable, therefore replace returns a new String for you to use

try

```
 i = i.replace(i.substring(0, i.indexOf('.') + 3), "");
```

Although try using

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Comment: More information about immutability in java [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code:

- You want to add two, not three, to the index of the decimal point,
- You cannot use `replace` without assigning back to the string,
- Your code assumes that there are no identical cash values.

For the last point, if you start with `2.222.222.22`, you would get only one cash value instead of three, because `replace` would drop all three matches.

Java offers a nice way of splitting a `String` on a regex:

```
String[] parts = S.split("(?<=[.]..)")
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/ip19ri)

The regex is a look-behind that expects a dot followed by any two characters.