# Do adding objects to an ArrayList clone?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, clone

I just recently learned cloning in Java. There is deep cloning and shallow cloning. I was wandering what does the ArrayList does when objects added to it. Does it clon?

I made some tests with String object.

```
String s = new String("hello");
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(s);
s = s.replace('h','y');
System.out.prinln(list.get(0));
```

It printed out "hello". So it does clon. Then I remembered from personal experience, when I add objects I wrote to an array, it doesn't clon. When I change the one in the array, original changes too.

I searched google, not sure because my lack of searching skills, I didn't find the answer I was looking for. Then I searched StackOverFlow, again nothing I was looking for.

So what is the deal with ArrayList? I am sorry if this question is duplicate, I really searched.

**Some people didn't understand the question:** Does ArrayList clon? (which is the main question I am looking the answer of) If not so why String did get cloned?

Comment: it doesn´t clone. In this case you are just noticing that the `String` is immutable.

Comment: Because String is immutable!

Comment: String immutability. The following is a good reading on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Comment: `s = s.replace('h','y');` does not modify the string. It returns a *new* string. The ArrayList still has a reference to the old string.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify objects inside an array and the changes will remain if the object is mutable. **String is inmmutable** and you cant change it, every time you make any function/action over a String it returns a new String Object with the result.

ArrayList doesn't clone objects, its just an array of objects and if they are mutable you can get and modify them.

If you need a mutable string you can use the StringBuilder object:

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder("Hi!");
string.append(" - concat new String");
System.out.println(string.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that manipulating the content of the list doesn't clone by checking its [identityHashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)). It will remain the same.

Comment: I can find out If any object is clonned with this? WIll it be different for every object?

Comment: Yes, for example try:
        System.err.println(System.identityHashCode(s) + " vs. " + System.identityHashCode(s.replace('h', 'y')));

Comment: Just to be clear, difference in identityHashCode indicates that the objects are different instances, this covers the clone scenario as well as String.replace when a new String is created