# Wierd String error, please be gracious, new to java

Tags: java, loops, compiler-errors, instantiation

So my problem is that it keeps saying I already defined `String spaces` up top but if I take the definition that's outside of the loop away and try to define `spaces` only in the loop, it tells me it hasn't been instantiated...

```
public class NestedLoop {
 public static void main (String [] args) {

  int userNum  = 0;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 1;
  String spaces = "";
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter userNum:");
  userNum = scnr.nextInt();

   for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++)   {
     while (j == i){
        spaces = spaces.concat(" ");
        System.out.print(spaces);
        j++;}
        System.out.println(i);}
```

Error: main.java:244: spaces is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Comment: @Baderous Has nothing to do with immutability here. However, what is the error with the current code?

Comment: main.java:244: spaces is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: also, main.java:259: spaces is already defined in main(java.lang.String[])

Comment: Then you've already defined a variable. You can't re-define a variable. In the posted code, `spaces` is only defined once so this can't throw the error...

Comment: what I'm trying to do is add `i` spaces before I print `int i` and then add a new line.  How would I go about that?

Comment: This is only part of the code. You are not showing the part of the code after the loops. Please [edit] your question and mark with a comment which line is 244 and which line is 259. Also, add the errors to the question itself, this is important information and shouldn't be lost in the comments.

Comment: Your code runs fine, though indentation sucks, and it won't do much with `userNum = 0`. Changing `userNum` to a higher value will print more, but probably not what you expected. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hesnap) for result.

Comment: The site itself defines values for `userNum` so I didn't need to worry about that.

Comment: and yeah, I fixed the loops, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this code in my IDE and got no errors, compile time or run time. Not sure I can replicate the errors you're reporting. Only possibility I could think of is an error with your JDK, but at the same time I dunno how or why that would occur.

Comment: I'm using a site called Zybooks (virtual textbook site).  So it's probably just a stupid error with the site. Thanks

Comment: @David See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/hesnap) for running version of your code, and results when setting `userNum = 3`.

Comment: Yup, just edited and fixed it, thanks

Comment: If you're new to Java programming and are still looking for a good IDE to work with, I recommend JetBrains IntelliJ. Community edition is free and has everything you'll need to write and debug code. Link: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/