# String parsing, replace new line character

Tags: java, regex, string

I have one issue regarding string parsing.

```
String str = "jdaskks sms=<hello
hi wini>";
```

Here u can see, the new line character present in string.
I have written a program, which searches for `sms= string` , then gets substring from `< >` character. in which i check for new line character and replace it with **'
'**.

But i have issue, when i get substring  . i replace it. but how to change this in original string str, as i can see change in substring not in original string.

Help is appreciated.

```
str.substring(j,str.indexOf('>',j+1)).replaceAll("\n", "#10");
here j is index of '<'
```

If i assign this string, i will get the substring with replace char, not original string with replaced new line character

Comment: So, you just get the string between `<...>` and replace the newline with a regular space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutability of Strings in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, but i need to change in original string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java - operations like `replace` don't actually update the original string. You have to use the return value of the `substring` call, e.g.

```
String updated = str.substring(j,str.indexOf('>',j+1)).replaceAll("\n", "#10");
```

If you want to replace this in the overall string, you can simply concatenate this back into the string:

```
int indexOf = str.indexOf('>',j+1);
str = str.substring(0, j)
    + str.substring(j,indexOf).replaceAll("\n", "#10"))
    + str.substring(indexOf);
```

Comment: But, original string will be lost right. as in my example, jdaskks will be lost. i will get substring, not the original string with replaced new line character

Comment: what part dont you understand about immutable?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get the substring but you are not assigning it to a string or using for displaying.Because strings are `immutable`.

So just assign result to a new string:

```
String result= str.substring(j,str.indexOf('>',j+1)).replaceAll("\n", "#10");
```

or use it for displaying.

```
System.Out.Println(str.substring(j,str.indexOf('>',j+1)).replaceAll("\n", "#10"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have created a new String object but didn't assign it back to a variable, is the cause of you issue.