# Access object inside abstract class

Tags: java, class, abstract

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
public abstract class ServerClass extends AsyncServer {

    private Validator serverValidator;

    public ServerClass(Validator val) {

        serverContext = ctx;
        serverValidator = val;
    }

    public start() {

        result(serverValidator.start("foo"));
    }

    abstract void result(String r);
};
```

Then, I call this method as follows:

```
ServerClass server = new ServerClass(validator) {

    @Override
    void result(String r) {

        useString(r);
    }
};
```

But for some reason the String r (returned from result()) is null. Is there something wrong in this code?

Comment: See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: How does your validator look?

Comment: _String r (returned from result())_ this method returns nothing, I don't understand

Comment: i think you are not passing string argument at all to method result(). have look at it.

Comment: but your result() method doesn't return anything.

Comment: You cannot modify the passed-in String. Strings in Java (and many languages) are immutable. You can [read a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java) about this concept online.

Comment: the method: validator.start("foo") works fine outside ServerClass class.