# When string is immutable, how come System.out.println(s.concat("some string")); returns the changed value

Tags: java, string, immutability

I have written following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = new String("abc");
    System.out.println(s.concat("def"));
}
```

it is returning me the output : "abcdef"

how is this possible if string is immutable.

Comment: Some what Similar Question answered well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 6):

`s.concat("def")` returns a new `String` instance. The `String` instance referenced by `s` remains unchanged.

You can add another `println` statement to see that for yourself :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("abc");
    System.out.println(s.concat("def"));
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

You can also see that in the Javadoc of `concat` :

> If the length of the argument string is 0, then this String object is returned. Otherwise, a String object is returned that represents a character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence represented by this String object and the character sequence represented by the argument string.

The original `String` is returned only if you pass an empty `String` to this method.

Comment: Checked the implementation of concat method. It returns a new string. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

It returns a new new String not a changed String

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = new String("abc");
    System.out.println(s.concat("def"));
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)),

```
public String concat(String str)
Concatenates the specified string to the end of this string.
```

> If the length of the argument string is 0, then this String object is
>   returned. Otherwise, **a new String object is created**, representing a 
>   character sequence that is the concatenation of the character sequence
>   represented by this String object and the character sequence
>   represented  by the argument string.

```
Examples:

 "cares".concat("s") returns "caress"
 "to".concat("get").concat("her") returns "together"
```

> Parameters: str - the String that is concatenated to the end of this
>   String.
>
> Returns: a string that represents the concatenation of this object's 
>   characters followed by the string argument's characters.