# Java, multiple letters assigned to one variable

Tags: java

I'm working on a while-loop which should check a text and see if letters are in CAPS or not as well as if they are vowels etc. I'm not sure of how to create a variable which can store certain letters. I asked this question yesterday an was told to use Array, but im wondering theres anyway to do this with help of Strings,charAt.

Comment: you should use String object.

Comment: If you have a string (like `String foo = "abc"`), you can iterate through characters with a loop like `for (int i=0; i<foo.length(); i++) { char c = foo.charAt(i); ..... }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop :-

```
String s = "HELLO";
if(s.toUpperCase().equals(s)){
    System.out.println("String is All-CAPS!");
}
```

Comment: But in this case you should know that after call s.toUpperCase() String s will be changed to UpperCase

Comment: @VugarSuleymanov No, it won't. `Strings` are **immutable**. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can just iterate over the String with charAt() for every position. If you have a String text:

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.length() ; i++){
    char currentChar = text.charAt(i);
    doSomething(currentChar);
}
```