# A method that removes a specific substring from a string

Tags: java, string, substring

I have this method that removes a specific letter from the string

```
public static String removeSpecificLetter(String s, String letter){
    s.replaceAll(letter, "");
    return s;
}
```

and when I try to print it using the code below it returns "aabbcc"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "aabbcc";
    System.out.println(removeSpecificLetter(s1, "a"));
}
```

Comment: Carefully read the Javadoc for `replaceAll()`, remembering that Strings are _immutable_ in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java) in java, which means that:

```
s.replaceAll(letter, "");
```

doesn't replace the original value of `s`, but returns a new string with the replaced values. Hence `return s;` will return the same original String. You can do this:

```
public static String removeSpecificLetter(String s, String letter){
    return s.replaceAll(letter, "");
}
```

This time we return directly the newer String version with the values already replaced.