# Java manipulating substring/char in a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a string array in JAVA like:

```
String[] fruits = {"banana", "apple", "orange"};
```

How can I access to a character/substring of a string member? For example I want to show the second character of first member "banana" which is 'a' and change it to 'b'. Should I make a new string equal to my array member, do the manipulation and assign the new string to my array list like this:

```
string manipulate = fruits[0];
//do manipulation on 'manipulate' then:
fruits[0] = manipulate;
```

or there is a builtin or better way?

Thanks

Comment: `fruits[index].charAt(index)`?

Comment: One thing is for sure, to update/replace string reference, you will have to create a new `String` object

Comment: What is your question about, arrays or string manipulation or object reference or....?

Comment: @AshishSingh Not necessarily, because you could define a function which manipulates strings as desired, then assign fruits[0] to its manipulated version.

Comment: @ Adi219 In that string function you will return a new `String` object, because as known, `String` object are immutable and cannot be changed/manipulated

Comment: @AshishSingh Ohhh I see what you meant now, yes you're right, but the `String` object will be created inside the function, not outside like here in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `String`s are immutable, meaning you can't change them. Instead, as @AshishSingh notes in the comments, you'll need to create a new `String`.

Just do this:

```
fruits[0] = manipulate(fruits[0]);
```

Here, `manipulate()` is your function which takes an input string, manipulates it however you want, and then `return`s the manipulated `string`.

```
public String manipulate(String oldStr) {
    StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder(oldStr);
    newStr.setChar(1, 'b')
    return newStr.toString();
}
```

I'm using `StringBuilder` which is a mutable object, so can have elements reassigned. I set the second character to 'b' and then `return` the new `String`.

Comment: `StringBuilder` does not mutate existing `String` value. However `StringBuilder` is by itself is mutable object.

Comment: @AwanBiru I never said it mutates existing `String`s; I said it allows mutable strings (I'm using the English sense of the word strings here, not the Java sense). However, I'll edit it just to make it clearer.

Comment: `StringBuilder.toString() ` will produce new `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The Java `String` object is immutable, so you can't modify its internal value.

```
char charArray[] = fruits[index].toCharArray();
charArray[2] = 'b';
```

After modifying the elements in the character array, put it back into `fruits` array.

```
fruits[index] = String.valueOf(charArray);
```

The existing `fruits[index]` will be replaced by the new `String`.

Comment: What's the difference between this answer and the answer from @ArnaudDenoyelle ?

Comment: About the same, unfortunately he posted first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a particular character of a String, use, `String.charAt(index)`.

That said, you cannot change a character in a `String` because [`Strings` are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java) in `Java`.

If you want to change a character in a given `String`, you will actually have to create a new `String`.

Example :

```
String[] fruits = {"banana", "apple", "orange"};

String banana = fruits[0];
char[] chars = banana.toCharArray();
chars[0] = 'c';
chars[4] = 'd';
String newStr = String.valueOf(chars);
System.out.println(newStr);
```

Output :

```
canada
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

```
int indexOfArray=1;
int indexOfString=1;
char charToChange='x';          
String fruits[] = {"banana", "apple", "orange"};            

StringBuilder manipulate = new StringBuilder(fruits[indexOfArray]);
manipulate.setCharAt(indexOfString, charToChange);
fruits[indexOfArray]=manipulate.toString();
```