# How to dynamically replace string in java?

Tags: java

I am trying use String.replace(oldChar,newChar) , but this returns a Changed string.
 Example:

```
String tempString= "abc is very easy";
String replacedString=tempString.replace("very","not");
System.out.println("replacedString is "+replacedString);
System.out.println("tempString is "+tempString);
```

OUTPUT :

```
replacedString is abc is not easy
tempString is abc is very easy
```

So my question is there any way to replace string without storing it in another String.

I want output of

```
String tempString= "abc is very easy";
tempString.replace("very","not");
System.out.println("tempString is "+tempString);
```

as

```
tempString is abc is not easy.
```

by using replace function.

Comment: I there some reason you want to do that? If it's particularly important, use a `StringBuffer`. But chances are it's not important.

Comment: You can't as String is `Immutable`

Comment: Are you looking for : `String tempString = "abc is very easy".replace("very", "not");`?

Comment: @pvg you probably mean `StringBuilder` - there's no indication OP wants a thread-safe mutable `CharSequence` here. But they'd be better off understanding immutability and the benefits thereof first.

Comment: Use a mutable `CharSequence` (e.g. a `StringBuilder`) instead of a string if you need this.

Comment: Thanks everyone..i got answer from @Tschallacka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable. They cannot change. Any action you perform on them will result in a "new" string that is returned by the method you called upon it.

Read more about it: [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

So in your example, if you wish to change your string you need to do to overwrite the variable that references your original string, to point to the new string value.

```
String tempString= "abc is very easy";
tempString = tempString.replace("very","not");
System.out.println("tempString is "+tempString);
```

Under the hood for your understanding:

> Assign String "abc is very easy" to memory address 0x03333
>   Assign address 0x03333 to variable tempString
>   Call method replace, create new modified string at address 0x05555
>   Assign address 0x05555 to temp String variable
>   Return temp String variable from method replace
>   Assign address from temp String variable to variable tempString
>   Address from tempString is now 0x05555.
>   If string at 0x03333 was not in code defined string and in StringPool String at address 0x03333 will be garbage collected.

Comment: Here you are still storing the result in string..any way without storing it ,just get result   dynamically

Comment: @Dhanraj you can not change a string "dynamically". Once you change something, a new String object gets created. You need to re-assign this to itself or a new String object.

Comment: @Dhanraj I added an explanation of how it works ish under the hood.

Answer (score -1):

You can reassign `tempString` with its new value :

```
String tempString= "abc is very easy";
tempString = tempString.replace("very","not");
System.out.println("tempString is "+tempString);
```

Result is :

```
tempString is abc is not easy
```

Best

Comment: We posted at the same time ^^' The other answer was not complete at the time I posted and has been updated and filled with details after. I did not want to post the same answer.