# In Java, how can I create a method where I can remove/add letters or numbers to a certain String?

Tags: java, string, substring, string-length

I know how to access a certain string spot using a for loop and doing string.substring(i), but I do not know to remove or add letters/numbers.

String.substring(i).replace("x", "");

```
public static String replace(String s) {
    for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.substring(i) == ... ) {
                //more code
            }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it still prints the original String.

Comment: Too many problems with your code.  1) Strings in Java are immutable, which means if you want a substring operation to "stick," you have to reassign it to another String.  2) Strings in Java are not compared using `==`.  Use `equals()` method instead.

Comment: Java String class does not provide mentioned methods but there can be different workarounds to achieve this (adding/removing). String will always return new instance as it's immutable.

Comment: Do you want to replace a certain character with another, no matter where, or how many times, in the string it appears?

Comment: Note that in java [`String` is immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java); you can't "set" a character, you have to make a new String.

Comment: check the code it will help you ,use a java compiler.   public class HelloWorld{
    
    
    static void remove(String replaceWord,String fullWord){
        String result = fullWord.replace(replaceWord,"");
        System.out.println("Final Result:"+result);
    }
    

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String fullWord = "DataSet";
        String removeWord = "Set";
        remove(removeWord, fullWord);
     }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String` is immutable in java . You can make `StringBuilder` object from `String` and do remove and add opertaion on it. `StringBuilder` gives you a methods `deleteCharAt`  and `setCharAt`. You can use them and in the end you can again get your new String back by calling method `toString` from `StringBuilder` object.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("yourString");
for(int i=0;i<sb.length();i++){
    if(sb.charAt(i) == '5'){ // want to compare '5' 
      sb.deleteCharAt(i);
    } else {
      sb.setCharAt(i,'6');
    }
}
String newString = sb.toString;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of StringBuilder?

Comment: @NicholasChen `StringBuilder` is Mutable and it performs additional operations and  faster than Strings. Have a look at this https://www.journaldev.com/538/string-vs-stringbuffer-vs-stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned operations cannot be directly achieved by Java String but can be achieved by [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Insert example:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Hello ");
    System.out.println("String :- " + stringBuilder);

    String string = "World";
    stringBuilder.insert(6, string);

    System.out.println("After insertion :- " + stringBuilder.toString());
}
}
```

Delete example:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("Hello World");

    System.out.println("Value:- " + stringBuilder);

    stringBuilder.delete(4, 9);
    System.out.println("After deletion :- " + stringBuilder);
}
}
```

Comment: How about replacing a letter in a string?

Comment: String provides `replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` method for replacement of a character in String but as said earlier String is immutable, it'll return new String object after replacement.

Answer (score 0):

In Java Strings are immutable objects until you reassign the reference it won't point to the modified object.

```java
        String str = "Hello work";

        if(str.substring(6).equals("work")) {
            str = str.replace(str.substring(6), "World!");
        }
```