# There are no compiler errors but it didn't change the string

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that changes the case of two characters in a string (change uppercase to lowercase and vice versa).It compiled, but the string is the same.

```
String newChar1 = caseChanger("DcoderIsCool", 3); 
String newChar2 = caseChanger("DcoderIsCool", 8);
```

I think the problem is with the method i used:

```
public static String caseChanger (String s, int ind) {
    if(!(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(ind)))) { 
        //checking if the character is uppercase or lowercase
        return s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toLowerCase();
    } else {
        return s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toUpperCase();        
    }
}
```

The output should have been "DcoDerIscool", but it's "DcoderIsCool" (the original string).

Comment: Where is the part of the code where you call the function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Comment: Also, assuming that by "errors" you mean "compiler errors", "There are no errors" is a rather low bar to clear. You also need to check for logical error, which the compiler can't know about.

Comment: Check your condition: if character is *not* uppercase, you convert it to lower case. That doesn't seem right...

Comment: if (!uppercase) return lowercase ?

Comment: Your condition is wrong: remove the not `!` from it.

Comment: yes, sorry, i meant compiler errors. thank you

Comment: it works now. thank you to all of you! i wasn't sure what the ! meant, i copied that from an answered question

Comment: As a general rule, don't use code you don't understand. This is just one way it could go wrong. But it could go much worse. Also, read some basic java tutorial. And good luck with your learning :)

Comment: yeah, you're right. thank you! i'm still learning the basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood your question right.

below code will give you output `DcoDerIsCool` and `DcoderIscool`.

```
public static String caseChanger(String s, int ind) {

    char[] charArr = s.toCharArray();

    if (!(Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(ind)))) {
        charArr[ind] = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(ind));
    } else {
        charArr[ind] = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(ind));
    }
    return String.valueOf(charArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this is what you are looking for

```
public static String caseChanger (String s, int ind) {
    if((Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(ind)))) { //checking if the character is uppercase or lowercase

        return new StringBuilder(s).replace(ind,ind+1,s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toLowerCase()).toString();
    }
    else {
        return new StringBuilder(s).replace(ind,ind+1,s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toUpperCase()).toString();        }
}
```

So you are changing only n charecter and returning those changed charecteres beside the extra not ! you are adding meaning your if condition is the other way arround. But what you are looking for is to replace the chars at the position you want in the original String. if im not mistaken.
Hope it helps

Comment: thank you! as suggested, i removed the "!" and it works now, but your code is more straight-forward, so i will also change the return statements :)

Comment: Use StringBuilder, not StringBuffer.  StringBuffer forces synchronization overhead on every method, which has no benefit in single-threaded logic, and rarely has any benefit even in multi-threaded logic.

Answer (score 0):

You fetched the character from string but didn't placed back into string
s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toLowerCase() is applied to single character

Instead doing return s.substring(ind, ind + 1).toLowerCase();

Replace the CaseChanged character back into the original string.