# Using variable from another java file

Tags: java

I am trying to make an app which import data from database and use it in another function.

I got connection with database and it returns me a variable called miejsce:

```
public void sprawdzAuto(String nrRej, String miejsce){
     try{
            String query = "select lokalizacja from samochody75 where nrRej=?";
            PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, nrRej);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                miejsce = rs.getString(1);
                System.out.println(miejsce);

            }


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Znaleziono.");


     } catch(SQLException e) {
         System.out.print(e);
     }
 }
```

Now when i got **miejsce** i want to use it in another .java file called Mapa.

```
public class Mapa extends MapView{
    private Map map;
    public Mapa(String nName)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(nName);

        setOnMapReadyHandler(new MapReadyHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(MapStatus status) {
                if (status == MapStatus.MAP_STATUS_OK){
                    map=getMap();

                    MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();
                    MapTypeControlOptions controlOptions= new MapTypeControlOptions();
                    mapOptions.setMapTypeControlOptions(controlOptions);

                    map.setOptions(mapOptions);
                    map.setCenter(new LatLng(1,1));
                    map.setZoom(17.0);

                    Marker mark = new Marker(map);
                    mark.setPosition(map.getCenter());
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(700,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I want result of **miejsce** to map.setCenter();
I tried diffrent things but none of them works.
Is there any solution to make it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I tried different things": Please show what you tried.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you want to accomplish... you set your map to latlong 1,1..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to missunderstand a lot of concepts about how scope and Java in general works. You should try and find a [java tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm) **before** posting on StackOverflow.

Here are some tips that can help you in your problem.

- You are iterating through a `ResultSet` which means you probably **won't have** only one result. So when you write `miejsce = rs.getString(1);` only the **last** value of your result set will be stored in your string.
- `String` is an [immutable object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553110/12624874). Which means that when you pass a `String` as a parameter to a method, you will not be able to access the value of your `String` from the calling method **unless** you return it from the called method. And that's not what you are doing here.
- To complete my two previous points and to solve partially yours, you can take a look at [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true) in java. Where you can store objects and values, strings **included**, and you **will be** able to access the content of your list, filled from the called method (`sprawdzAuto` here), from your calling method.

I won't do the code for you, I think it is better if you do some digging yourself.

Hope this helps.