# Change a string, within a method, that should be outside the method

Tags: java

First, I wanna show my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put("bye",0);
        map.put("Hello",1);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map(map, new BiConsumer<String,Integer>(){
            @Override
            public void accept(String s, Integer i){
                s=s+"s";
            }
        })));
    }
    
    public static String[] map(Map<String,Integer> m, BiConsumer<String,Integer> bif){
        String[] key = m.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] entries = new String[m.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
            bif.accept(key[i],m.get(key[i]));
            entries[i] = key[i] + ", " + m.get(key[i]);
        }
        return entries;
    }
```

As you can see, I would like to develop a method that accepts a Map<String, Integer> and BiConsumer<String, Integer>, that does what the passed function wants to do with every key and value from the map and that finally returns a String array.

One could say: a method that does roughly that what forEach does:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-

I was able to add the BiConsumer interface because it doesn't depend on other Java 8 classes.

I need to develop this method without changing anything in the following code as possible and **only with Java 7**:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(map(map, new BiConsumer<String,Integer>(){
            @Override
            public void accept(String s, Integer i){
                s=s+"s";
            }
        })));
```

Expected result:

> [byes, 0, Hellos, 1]

But I am getting:

> [bye, 0, Hello, 1]

So I don't know, whether I should change the string within a method that is just outside the method.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show how your code is not working? Show the expected result and actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
s=s+"s";
```

creates a new `String` and stores it in `s`. Before the assignment, `s` stores a reference to the same object as `keys[i]` does. After the assignment, since `s` refers to a new object, totally unrelated to what `keys[i]` refers to. In fact, you cannot change the string in `keys[i]` by changing `s`, even though `s` refers to the same object as `keys[i]` at the beginning of the method. This is because `String` is immutable. See also: [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

What you *can* do, is have the `BiConsumer` return the new string that is created, and on the caller's side, assign the returned string to `keys[i]`. At this point, we no longer have a `BiConsumer<String, Integer>` anymore, but a `BiFunction<String, Integer, String>`:

```
interface BiFunction<T, U, R> {
    R apply(T t, U u);
}
```

`map` would look like this:

```
public static String[] map(Map<String,Integer> m, BiFunction<String,Integer, String> bif){
    String[] key = m.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] entries = new String[m.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) {
        Integer value = m.get(key[i]);
        String newKey = bif.apply(key[i], value); // note here!
        entries[i] = newKey + ", " + value;

        // uncomment if you want the map's keys to also change
        /*
        m.remove(key[i]);
        m.put(newKey, value);
        */
    }
    return entries;
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
map(map, new BiFunction<>(){
        @Override
        public void apply(String t, Integer u){
            return t + "s";
        }
    })
```

Comment: In my case I don't need to change the value. But if someone want to do this, he can't, because BiFunction<String, Integer, String> can only return one object per method. So I wanted to pass one method to my map() method, that can change the passed string and the passed integer and returns both. However I accept your answer because you explained the stuff very well!! 

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as you may have experienced, Java Strings are immutable. This means, whenever you write something like `s = s + s;`, you are creating a new object. Additionally, Java is always pass-by-value. So any Object references (like the String here in the accept method) are also passed by value. This means doing things like -

```
void method(String s){
    s = new String();
}
```

will also not change the reference outside the method.

There are some ways to get around this but it's a bit of a hassle. You essentially store the String reference in a new class, then operate on that. Here's a demonstration:

```
public class StringRefContainer{
    public String str;
    StringRefContainer(String str){this.str = str;}
}

// example accept method
void accept(StringRefContainer s, Integer i){
    // operate directly on s.str
    // eg s = s + 's'
    s.str = s.str + "s";
}
```

Obviously, you can improve this according to your use case (eg, override toString, hashcode, equals, etc for StringRefContainer class, or change/add access specifiers to suit your design, etc).