# I am trying to replace the pattern "our" in the string to become "or" however this is not working

Tags: java, string, replace

String str1 = "The rumour is that the neighbours displayed good behaviour by labouring to help Mike because he is favoured.";

str1.replaceAll("our", "or");

System.out.println(str1);

Comment: `String`s are immutable - `str1.replaceAll("our", "or");` does not change `str1`.  The result (a new `String`) needs to be assigned and used.  For example: `str1 = str1.replaceAll("our", "or");`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it doesn't answer this question. Because answer to question "why string doesn't changed" is "string immutability". And "[Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)" is the answer to question "what is string immutability".

Answer (score 1):

Method `replaceAll` returns a new string where each occurrence of the matching substring is replaced with the replacement string.

Your code doesn't work because `String` is immutable. So, `str1.replaceAll("our", "or");` doesn't change `str1`.

Try this code:

```
    String str1 = "I am trying to replace the pattern.";
    String str2 = str1.replaceAll("replace", "change");
    System.out.println(str2);
```

If you don't what `str2`, try this code:

```
    String str1 = "I am trying to replace the pattern.";
    System.out.println(str1.replaceAll("replace", "change"));
```

And read about [Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java).