# Changing arrays inside a method also changes them permanently. Does this apply to Strings too, since they are objects?

Tags: java, arrays, string, object, parameters

I do know that when you pass an array as a parameter into a method and then alter it in some way, the original array will be changed. However, does this also apply to Strings?

If you have these variables:

```
int[] testArray = {1,2,3};
String testString = "helloWorld";
```

And these methods:

```
static int[] changeFirstEntryToZero(int[] array) {
        array[0] = 0;
        return array;
}

static String changeString(String s) {
        s = "changed";
        return s;
}
```

And then in the main method you do this:

```
System.out.println(testArray[0]);
changeFirstEntryToZero(testArray);
System.out.println(testArray[0]);

System.out.println(testString);
changeString(testString);
System.out.println(testString);
```

Then the result is this:

1

0

helloworld

helloworld

That tells me that it does not permanently change the String. But why?

I thought that Strings are objects too in Java. Is there something I'm missing, or is it that simple?

Could a String accidentally be permanently changed if I did something slightly different.

Comment: String is immutable, better to  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java

Comment: You are modifying (the contents of) the array, but you are not modifying the string, you are assigning a different string to the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your first method:

```java
static int[] changeFirstEntryToZero(int[] array) {
    array[0] = 0;
    return array;
}
```

when you use `array[0] = 0` you are deferencing the array and accessing the first element of the original array passed to the method.  You may conceptually think of passing an array as passing a reference to the original array.

On the other hand, in the second method:

```java
static String changeString(String s) {
    s = "changed";
    return s;
}
```

the string `s` is a variable which is *local* to the method.  When the method is called, it will be assigned the value of the string being passed in.  However, making an assignment to `s` only affects this local string, and not the original string which was passed in.