# How to replace slash with underscore

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hints for java.lang.String.replace problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166905/hints-for-java-lang-string-replace-problem)
>   [Using string.replace() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734721/using-string-replace-in-java)

Why "/" does not replaced by "_" ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file = "A/B";
    file.replaceAll("/", "_");
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

Comment: Also, don't use `replaceAll` when all you need is `replace`. It's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because instances of `java.lang.String` are *immutable*<sup>*</sup>.  `replaceAll` returns the correct string, but your program throws it away. Change your program as follows to correct the issue:

```
file = file.replaceAll("/", "_");
```

---

<sup>*</sup> That's a fancy way of saying "non-changeable": once a string instance `"A/B"` is created, there are no methods that you could call on it to change that value.

Answer (score 3):

You need to store the result of the `file.replaceAll()` call as `String` instances are immutable:

```
file = file.replaceAll("/", "_");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign the result of the replaceAll:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file = "A/B";
    String newFile = file.replaceAll("/", "_");
    System.out.println(newFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file.replaceAll("/", "_");
```

Since, String in Java is **immutable**, so **any method of String class,** not just `replaceAll`, does not modify the existing String.. Rather they create a new String and return that.. So you should re-assign the returned string to the `file`..

```
file = file.replaceAll("/", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at [String.replaceAll javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll): it returns a String.

Method like this won't modifies their parameter.
So you need to write:

```
String file = "A/B";
file = file.replaceAll("/", "_");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about **immutable** property.

[Immutable property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279507/what-is-meant-by-immutable)

[Why are strings immutable in many programming languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544182/why-are-strings-immutable-in-many-programming-languages)