# String replacement with "" Java

Tags: java, string

Say I have a string, `String x = "oncetherewasaboy";`
I want to replace `"there"` with `""`. I tried `x.replace("there","");` But this does not remove it. This is not the best example but I am doing it for an array of strings and want to clean and filter some of the information inside each index with `""`. Thanks!

Comment: Javadoc is your friend. Just quoting the return statement of `replace` : `Returns : a string derived from this string by replacing every occurrence of oldChar with newChar.`

Comment: ^^ `Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.` Strings are immutable in Java; you can't change them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hints for java.lang.String.replace problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166905/hints-for-java-lang-string-replace-problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings are immutable. Calling `replace()` doesn't change the string. It creates a new one, and returns it. You need to save the reference to it in a variable, or else you can't access it. You need:

```
x = x.replace("there", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

String is an immutable Type. An immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. So you can not modify the string x.

So as you can not modify the string, the replace method returns a new string with the new changes. So as jlordo has already suggested you need to use like following

```
x = x.replace("there", "");
```