# how to remove \r and \n from my string in java?

Tags: java, json, string

I'm just trying to remove (replace with "") \r and \n from my JSON. Here is the method I'm currently testing which doesn't work.

```
    public static void testing(){
        String string = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
        string.replace("\r", "");
        string.replace("\n", "");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `String.replace` returns the modified string. You need `string = string.replace(...)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hints for java.lang.String.replace problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166905/hints-for-java-lang-string-replace-problem)

Comment: The awkward moment is that it works with normal strings but not working with jsonString. The testing method is fixed by you suggested, @khelwood.

Comment: One should never manipulate JSON strings directly. Use a proper JSON library instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex `(\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)` and String#replaceAll, like:

```
string = string.replaceAll("(\\r\\n|\\n|\\r)", "");
```

Comment: This is juz my mistake. I'll post another question. My testing method works  after assigning back but actual method I'm working doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

After replacing you need to assign back to the original string. Because the string is immutable you cannot change the value of a string.
You need to use

```
String string = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
string  = string.replace("\r", "");
string  = string.replace("\n", "");
```

Or you can use any libraries like Apache StringUtils.If you are using these utils , no needs to assign back the value to String

Comment: This is juz my mistake. I'll post another question. My testing method works  after assigning back but actual method I'm working doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static void testing(){
    String string = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
    string  = string.replace("\r", "");
    string  = string.replace("\n", "");
}
```

because replace return another string(new String) because String is immutable so unable to modified directly

Comment: This is juz my mistake. I'll post another question. My testing method works  after assigning back but actual method I'm working doesn't work.

Comment: Including yours, every answer is correct. But that's not what I need.

Comment: please edit your question and explain what you want to as exactly

Comment: do u want to replace \r and \n from json object??? if yes then do u want it from serverside or clientside???

Comment: Yap, I was about to post it as new post. But I already found the answer. It might be duplicated if I post it.

Comment: thz dude, here is what I found. data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");

Answer (score 1):

String.replace will return a string. It doesn't change its value.

```
public static void testing(){
    String str = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
    str = str.replace("\r", "");
    str = str.replace("\n", "");
}
```

Comment: This is juz my mistake. I'll post another question. My testing method works  after assigning back but actual method I'm working doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String string = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
    String newStr = string.replace("\r", "");
    newStr = newStr.replace("\n", "");
    System.out.println(newStr);
```

String will return new String Object.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    String string = "\rte\r\rs\nti\nn\ng";
    String newString = string.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
```

Comment: the answer is , data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");

Answer (score 0):

```java
String string = "\r\r\r\n\n\n";
string = string.replaceAll("\r", "");
string = string.replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
string = string.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

```
data_json = data_json.replaceAll("\\\\r\\\\n", "");
```

*Copied from OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008970/how-to-remove-r-and-n-from-my-string-in-java/68982458#comment53846733_33009129).*