# String replace not working, even after assigning to another variable

Tags: java, string

Java `String.replace` not working even after assigning to a variable.

I have a `JSON` formatted string like as follows.

`{"Obligations":["\nAggregate","\nDelay"],"Result":"Permit"}`

I want to remove the `\n` from the string.

I used the following piece of code. There is no difference.

```
    String test =jsonObject.toString().replace("\n", ""); 
    System.err.println(test);
```

But I get the same result. Is there something wrong in it ?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1166912/4852017) provide any assistance?

Comment: `\n` matches a literal new line. `\\n` matches the String pattern `\n`.

Comment: `.replace("\\n", "");`. Backslashes need to be escaped in string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

```
String test =jsonObject.toString().replace("\\n", ""); 
System.err.println(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

"\n" means a new line. You must use an escape.

Try it:

```
String test =jsonObject.toString().replace("\\n", "");
```